# How can I get the Alt key to work in an X11 application?

Tags: macos, keyboard, x11

I'm using an editor that requires X11 and for the most part it works well. I have many commands that use the Alt key and I like to navigate the menus this way as well, but the Alt key doesn't work through X11.

I found [this article](http://www.inkscapeforum.com/viewtopic.php?t=800&f=5) on configuring the Alt key for X11 applications, but it didn't work for me. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to check "Enable key equivalents under X11" in the Input tab of the X11 Preferences.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I already have that checked (the editor vendor had me try that).

Comment: I've found out this setting doesn't apply here. When enabled it means keystrokes like Command-N will be given to X11 (new terminal, in this case) instead of to the application itself. In my case I certainly want Alt-key to go to the application, not X11, so I have turned off "Enable key equivalents under X11".

Answer (score 1):

The distilled instructions in [this article](https://ewen.mcneill.gen.nz/blog/entry/2009-11-06-os-x-x11-alt-key/) worked for me.

in `~/.Xmodmap`:

```
clear Mod1
keycode 66 = Alt_L
keycode 69 = Alt_R
add Mod1 = Alt_L
add Mod1 = Alt_R
```

and activate with `xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap`. The codes 66 and 69 can be verified with `xev`.

I did not change any other input settings. Note the op's article used `Meta_R` instead of `Alt_R`. I tested with an ssh-xforwarded app (eclipse).