# How to access the Menu Mnemonics of an X11 Program within macOS

Tags: x11, macos

With the kind assistance of **X11 Quartz** background app I have an X11 app **Dia** diagramming tool running.

[image]

It is enticing to see those **mnemonics** apparently (?) available to use. I have a serious beef with macOS for not helping those of us who are keyboardists to have an option to work in that manner.

So, is it possible to access those mnemonics? I have tried various combinations of <kbd>Option</kbd>, <kbd>Control</kbd>, <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>Option</kbd>, with/without <kbd>Command</kbd> plus the given letter.

Comment: As the question turned out to be a duplicate do you still want to do the bounty?

Comment: @nohillside Once opened the bounty is a "done deal" afaik.  If not then sure you can cancel.

Comment: You can't, moderators can :-)

Comment: thx mr moderator ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just noticed a related question on this site:

[How can I get the Alt key to work in an X11 application?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/13745/how-can-i-get-the-alt-key-to-work-in-an-x11-application?rq=1)

[image]
It will take some time to try this out .. will report back in couple of days.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to create and source an `.Xmodmap`, and there are a few other preferences/things you need to change or clear too.

See https://gist.github.com/dreeve/845301 for a good modern example.